# Pattern to trigger a transaction in the future

Tags: design-patterns, database, polling

Is there a pattern to handle the following scenario :

I have a set of business transactions captured and stored in a mongoDB database that need to be executed at a future date that is also stored in the database. I'd like to build a process that will trigger regularly, scan the database and pick up the transactions that are due to be executed.

I know this can be done with a process like a cron job that wakes up periodically. That's fine if you only run one instance of the process, but if I have more than one such process running, there is likely to be duplication in the transactions processed.

Your input and suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks, 
Dex

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple processes, each process must lock the rows it wishes to process first.

```
UPDATE [table] set lockedby=@lockedby, lockedon=@lockedon WHERE lockedby IS NULL LIMIT [n]
```

Then select the rows that were just locked.  Each process should have a unique lockedby.  When done, delete the row(s).

One will need a sweeper process to unlock any rows that have been locked for a long period of time due to a crashed or hung process so that another worker proces can process them.

This is usually called pessimistic locking.